# How to migrate javascript from a multi-file example, in to a simple, single page?

Tags: javascript, html, auth0

I know this sounds like a ridiculously simple question, but there is a lot more to it than just a basic function call. I'm implementing authentication on a webapp using the Auth0 python example, they have a full example [available here](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-python-web-app/tree/master/00-Starter-Seed).

I completely understand the python Auth0 stuff, and can get all the details I require from the session, but I simply can NOT work out how to move this sample code in to my app using a simple "login" and "logout" button! The HTML from the sample app looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/auth0/8.6.0/auth0.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/iws6ohy.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- font awesome from BootstrapCDN -->
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script>
        var AUTH0_CLIENT_ID = '{{env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}}';
        var AUTH0_DOMAIN = '{{env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}}';
        var AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL = '{{env.AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL if env.AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL else "http://localhost:3000/callback" }}';
        var API_AUDIENCE = '{{env.API_IDENTIFIER}}';
        </script>
        <script src="/public/app.js"> </script>
        <link href="/public/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body class="home">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="login-page clearfix">
              <div class="login-box auth0-box before">
                <img src="https://i.cloudup.com/StzWWrY34s.png" />
                <h3>Auth0 Example</h3>
                <p>Zero friction identity infrastructure, built for developers</p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-login btn-block">SignIn</a>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Javascript that is running is contained in a seperate file that is read in on document load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var auth = new auth0.WebAuth({
    domain: AUTH0_DOMAIN,
    clientID: AUTH0_CLIENT_ID
   });


    $('.btn-login').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      auth.authorize({
        audience: 'https://'+AUTH0_DOMAIN+'/userinfo', // you can also set this on the .env file and put API_AUDIENCE instead
        scope: 'openid profile',
        responseType: 'code',
        redirectUri: AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL
      }); 
    });

    $('.btn-logout').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.location.href = '/logout';
    })
});
```

I don't want to use the standard HTML provided with the sample, all I want is a simple "login" button to, well log in the user, but for the life of me I simple don't understand how to make that happen. I want this to be as simple as possible, with all the javascript embedded in the page. I've tried the following, but it fails as the variable "e" is undefined, and I don't understand where it came from in the original example!

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/auth0/8.6.0/auth0.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/iws6ohy.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
      <p><button onclick="loginfunc()">Click me</button></p>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
           var auth = new auth0.WebAuth({
             domain: AUTH0_DOMAIN,
             clientID: AUTH0_CLIENT_ID
            });
         },
      </script>
      <script>
         function loginfunc(e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               auth.authorize({
                 audience: 'https://'+AUTH0_DOMAIN+'/userinfo', // you can also set this on the .env file and put API_AUDIENCE instead
                 scope: 'openid profile',
                 responseType: 'code',
                 redirectUri: AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL
               }); 
             }

      </script>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <!-- font awesome from BootstrapCDN -->
      <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script>
         var AUTH0_CLIENT_ID = '{{env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}}';
         var AUTH0_DOMAIN = '{{env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}}';
         var AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL = '{{env.AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL if env.AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL else "http://localhost:3000/callback" }}';
         var API_AUDIENCE = '{{env.API_IDENTIFIER}}';
      </script>
      <script src="/public/app.js"> </script>
      <link href="/public/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body class="home">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="login-page clearfix">
            <div class="login-box auth0-box before">
               <img src="https://i.cloudup.com/StzWWrY34s.png" />
               <h3>Auth0 Example</h3>
               <p>Zero friction identity infrastructure, built for developers</p>
               <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-login btn-block">SignIn</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I'm guessing lines 6 and 7 of the original HTML is where all the "magic" is happening, I just don't know how to "read" what's going on there.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/iws6ohy.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
```

I understand this is a horrible, horrible question, but I've been looking at this for hours now and I'm just ready to give up, I can't look at it any more. For the life of me I don't understand why Auth0 didn't just make a super simple, all-on-on-page example that anyone can understand, not all this fancy bootstrap/css/html mess!

If anyone can help, I will be eternally grateful!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I did it!!!

So it turns out I was waaaaay off, it had nothing to do with the script lines I was focusing on. Here is the working code:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/auth0/8.6.0/auth0.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         function loginfunc() {
             var auth = new auth0.WebAuth({
             domain: AUTH0_DOMAIN,
             clientID: AUTH0_CLIENT_ID
            });
               auth.authorize({
                 audience: 'https://'+AUTH0_DOMAIN+'/userinfo', // you can also set this on the .env file and put API_AUDIENCE instead
                 scope: 'openid profile',
                 responseType: 'code',
                 redirectUri: AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL
               }); 
             }

      </script>
      <script>
         var AUTH0_CLIENT_ID = '{{env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}}';
         var AUTH0_DOMAIN = '{{env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}}';
         var AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL = '{{env.AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL if env.AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL else "http://localhost:3000/callback" }}';
         var API_AUDIENCE = '{{env.API_IDENTIFIER}}';
      </script>
   </head>
   <body >
      <p><button onclick="loginfunc()">Click me</button></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Basically I just pulled the app.js code in to the main html file, then used a standard "onclick" button action to call the auth function. This is so much easier to read than the auth0 example.

I hope this makes the example clearer for someone else in the future. I find it really frustrating the developers confuse the core code example with completely unnecessary css and artys html formatting.